# Create class instance based on a string input

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2

Background:

In my game engine I have a generic 'script parser' which is used to create game entities by parsing a script file. So in code you would have something like `MyEntity* entity = MyScriptParer::Parse("filename.scr");`

Any class which is to be scriptable inherits from a generic base class. Internally in the game engine there are some specific classes that use this - particles, fonts etc and this all works nicely in the parser - see extract below

```
std::string line;
std::getline(ifs, line);

if (line == "[FONT]") {
    CFont* f = new CFont();
    f->readObject(ifs);
}
else if (line == "[PARTICLE]") {
    CParticle* p = new CParticle();
    p->readObject(ifs);
}
...
```

My problem comes with how to handle user defined classes i.e classes in the games that use the game engine. The base class has an abstract method `readObject` so anything which inherits must implement this method.

The issue is how would the parser know about the new class? E.g say I have a `CVehicle` class the parser would now need to know to recognise "[VEHICLE]" and also be able to create a `new CVehicle`

Is there any way to store a class type or something in an array/map so maybe I could have a function to register a list of class types with strings to provide a lookup for creating the new instances?

Bit of a long shot and may not be possible so if anyone has other suggestions on how to approach the parsing they will be welcomed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **can** store a class type in an array/map via [std::type_info](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info)

However, you cannot create a type from this, as it would require more RTTI than is available in C++. (like reflection in .NET).

However, you could store a function pointer to a class factory in such a map.
I.e.

```
typedef CBaseClass* (*pfnCreateClass)();

std::map<std::string, pfnCreateClass> mapCreate;

// Registering
// CMyCustomClass::GetClass() is a static method that creates a CMyCustomClass
mapCreate.insert(std::pair<std::string, pfnCreateClass>("[CUSTOM_CLASS]", CMyCustomClass::GetClass));

// Get class
std::map<std::string, pfnCreateClass>::const_iterator it = mapCreate.find(line);
if(mapCreate.end() != it)
{
    CBaseClass *p = it->second();
    p->readObject(ifs);
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the informative answer. I will give this a try and see how it goes.

Comment: OK I like this approach as it means I can make the complete script reader a bit more generic and have even internal scriptables added as new ones get added to the game engine. I have tried to implement and come across one issue though. It is with the `CMyCustomClass::GetClass()` part. If I try to pass it as per your example the compiler fails with "Cannot initialize a parameter of type 'CBaseClass *(*)()' with an lvalue of type 'CFont *()': different return type ('CBaseClass *' vs 'CFont *')"

Comment: I fixed my issue. Was a simple error of me passing back a pointer to the new customer class, `CFont` in this case, instead of passing it back a the base class pointer

Answer (score 0):

Just have the function to register a new type take in the name of the type and a function for creating the type.

Something like so:

```
void RegisterType( std::string name, std::function< BaseType() > createFunc );
```

When registering a new type you do it like so:

```
RegisterType( "Vehicle", [](){ return new CVehicle; } );
```

That way the parser can create all the derived types.